# Dynamic SQL Insert Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, insert

I have this statement below that was not working.  Any idea?

```
DECLARE @TargetDB NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @SourceDB NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @InsetRecords NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @TargetDB = 'MySSISDb'
SET @SourceDB = 'MySSISDb'

SET @InsetRecords = 'INSERT INTO  + @TargetDB + .dbo.Item2(ProductNumber, ProductName) SELECT(ProductNumber, ProductName) FROM  + @SourceDB + .dbo.Item'
EXEC (@InsetRecords)
```

Comment: What's not working? What error do you get? Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Dynamic SQL won't automatically parse the variables. Try this: `SET @InsetRecords = 'INSERT INTO ' + @TargetDB + '.dbo.Item2(ProductNumber, ProductName) SELECT(ProductNumber, ProductName) FROM ' + @SourceDB + '.dbo.Item'`

Comment: I'm using SQL2008R2.  This is the error I got.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '+'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: Thanks SchmitzIT.  I tried your suggestion but still giving problems but if it's only 1 column, it works.  Any idea why?  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be that your dynamic SQL is not really dynamic SQL. You are not inserting the value of the variable, but rather adding the variable name to the SQL String.

Try replacing the line:

```
SET @InsetRecords = 'INSERT INTO  + @TargetDB + .dbo.Item2(ProductNumber, 
ProductName) SELECT(ProductNumber, ProductName) FROM  + @SourceDB + .dbo.Item'
```

with:

```
SET @InsetRecords = 'INSERT INTO ' + @TargetDB + '.dbo.Item2(ProductNumber, 
ProductName) SELECT(ProductNumber, ProductName) FROM ' + @SourceDB + '.dbo.Item'
```

Comment: Thanks SchmitzIT. I tried this but still giving problem but if it's only 1 column, it works. It seems that having more than 1 column in table has syntax error.  Kindly help me if you can. Thanks a lot. I really appreciated your help.

Comment: Sounds odd. The syntax looks okay to me. Try this at the end. Instead of `EXEC (@InsetRecords`, use `PRINT @InsetRecords`. Paste the output here. You can also try using `EXEC sp_executeSQL` instead of `EXEC`. IT's specifically intended for dynamic SQL.